# How to drop the separator when concatenating two csv files with pandas?

Tags: python, python-2.7, parsing, csv, pandas

I have three `.csv` files like this, both of them have the same `id` and the same `tag`, but **different `text`**:

**.csv File one:**

```
id,text
ID_one_111,some text_1
...
ID_n-th_n,some text_n
```

**.csv File two**

```
id,text,tag
ID_one_111,some different text_1
...
ID_n-th_n,some different text_n
```

And a `tags` file like this

```
id,tag
ID_one_111,1
...
ID_n-th_n,5
```

However, I would like to generate a new csv file with the concatenation of the `text` column and the `tags` as follows:

```
id,text,tag
ID_one_111,some text_1 some different text_1,3
...
ID_n-th_n,some text_n some different text_n,5
```

For this, I was using [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) as follows, this is what I actually tried:

```
# -- coding: utf-8 --
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 3000)

df1=pd.read_csv('path/of/the/first/file.csv')

df2=pd.read_csv('path/of/the/second/file.csv').drop('id',1)

label = pd.read_csv('path/of/the/tag_file/tags.csv').drop('id',1)


new_df = pd.concat([df1,df2, label], axis=1)


new_df.reset_index(drop=True)

new_df.to_csv('path/of/the/new/file.csv',
              sep=',', encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

**The problem with this** approach is that I am getting something like this:

```
id,text,text,tag
ID_one_111,some text_1, some different text_1,3
...
ID_n-th_n,some text_n, some different text_n,5
```

Recall, how can I fix the above approach and merge both `text` columns and tag column in order to get something like this:

```
id,text,tag
ID_one_111,some text_1 some different text_1,3
...
ID_n-th_n,some text_n some different text_n,5
```

Any how, I read the [to_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) documentation but I did not found any "drop separator parameter". Thanks in advance guys.

**Update**

From an answer thanks to @maxymoo I tried this:

```
df_final = pd.DataFrame({'id':new_df.iloc[:,0],
                         'content':new_df.iloc[:,1] + ' ' + new_df.iloc[:,2],
                         'label':new_df.iloc[:,3]}).to_csv('new.csv',
              sep=',', encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

But the file just become a mess with the id, text, and tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution, albeit without using pandas:

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

rows = defaultdict(list)

for csv in ['csv_one.csv', 'csv_two.csv', 'csv_three.csv']:
    with open(csv) as f:
        next(f) # skips the header row
        reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
        for row in reader:
            rows[row[0]].append(row[1:])

with open('out.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')
    for k,v in rows.iteritems():
         writer.writerow([k]+v)
```

Comment: very elegant, Pandas certainly might be overkill for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to approach this is with a vectorized string operation on the two columns you have. Something like this:

```
df_final = pd.DataFrame({'ID':new_df.iloc[:,0], 
                         'text':new_df.iloc[:,1] + ' ' + new_df.iloc[:,2], 
                         'tag':new_df.iloc[:,3]})
```

Also you'd better make sure that all the ID's line up in your files, otherwise you might want to consider using `merge` rather than `concat`

Comment: Thanks for the help. Sorry but I did not understood how to use the above aproach, could you provide me some example in more detail?. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

An ordered dictionary can be used to preserve the line ordering based on your first file, and it will also work if the 3 CSV input files do not line up 100%. As mentioned, Pandas is possibly overkill for this operation.

The headers from each of the 3 source CSV files are also combined into your output CSV file.

```
import collections, csv

drows = collections.OrderedDict()
lheaders = []

for file in ["file_1.csv", "file_2.csv", "file_3.csv"]:
    with open(file, "r") as f_input:
        csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)
        headers = csv_input.next()
        lheaders.extend(headers[1:])

        for data_row in csv.reader(f_input):
            drows.setdefault(data_row[0], []).extend(data_row[1:])

with open("output.csv", "wb") as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
    csv_output.writerow([headers[0]] + lheaders)

    for id, row in drows.items():
        csv_output.writerow([id] + row)
```